# show() is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript with Eloquent Javascript.

I've written the following code on the Firefox console, but it returns :
"ReferenceError: show() is not defined" Why?

```
show(confirm("Shall we, then?"));
```

Comment: This is one of those questions where the clue is very much in the error message itself...

Comment: Well, did you define a `show` function? If not then that's the reason.

Answer (score 6):

The show function is implemented in the shell environment given by Eloquent Javascript, It's not a part of standard Javascript. You should checkout the online version of Eloquent Javasacript. http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter2.html and at the bottom of the page you will find the console. Type your statements there. Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

> I've written the following code on the Firefox console, but it returns
>   : "ReferenceError: show() is not defined" Why?

Because there is no such function `show` defined. You could use the `console.log` to write to the console:

```
console.log(confirm("Shall we, then?"));
```

Or if you don't want to log to the console simply invoke the [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm) function:

```
if (confirm("Shall we, then?")) {
    // the user confirmed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`show()` is not a method of `window` object, so it will work only if you defined a function called so in the global scope

if you type

```
 console.log(typeof window.show)
```

it should return `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Because `show` is not a defined property on the `window` object. In the browser, just try

```
confirm("Shall we, then?");
```

which will display a confirmation dialog. To display just an alert dialog,

```
alert("Shall we, then?");
```

Both of these actions block though, so it is good practice to log to the console (if it exists)

```
console.log("Shall we, then?");
```